# Post table data to action which is dynamically added to DataTable

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am posting table with dynamically added data to the controller action.

On the UI there is a form field to search **Terms** which are already added to the DB. User just search and add them to the table with a single click.

To post this table data to the action I am doing these steps:

**Step 1:**
Create array **TermsData** and fill it with the required data of the table.

```
var TermsData = [];
var dataRows = oTNCTable.rows().data();
for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
    TermsData.push({
        Name: dataRows.cell(i, 1).data(),
        DisplayName: dataRows.cell(i, 2).data(),
        Description: dataRows.cell(i, 3).data(),
        });
   }
```

**Step 2:** Convert this array to the json string.

```
var jsonTerms = JSON.stringify(TermsData);
```

**Step 3:** Add this json string to the form hidden field

```
$("#JsonTerms").val(jsonTerms);
```

**Step 4:** On the Action of the controller I am deserializing this string using model.

```
var QuoteTerms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TermsConditionsList>>(model.JsonTerms);
model.QuoteTermsConditions = QuoteTerms;
```

then processing this data.

its working fine until I have this issue:

> When the user entered **'&' symbol** in the data, I am receiving 
>   html as **&amp** in the action but I need **'&'** only to do processing.

So my questions are:

> 1. Is it a good approach to get the Jquery DataTable dynamically added data to the action?
> 2. If not then what should be the best approach?
> 3. What should I do to convert **&amp** back to the **& symbol**?

I just need all data to action as it is because user fetching data to the UI and then just adding it to the table and submitting it.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then that's not the approach I would use. Rather I'd add the search term to the backend database and only add the row to the table if it was added successfully. The data in you DB is the canonical data, not the data in your table and doing things the way I suggest makes sur that this is the case.

Comment: @annoyingmouse the data is already is in the DB, user just search the term and select that term and it will be added to the table then i'll just save the ids of table data.