# Datatable Jquery special character encoding and decoding to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I found out that html special characters such as **'&'** are not being decoded when we fetch value from the table object using API functions but instead of they are in ASCII or Unicode form. This is my simple initialization for the dataTable.

```
var otable = $('#vtable').DataTable({
        "dom": '<"top"lBf<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>'
});
```

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shhzdmrz/ccmeuLzu/).

> What should be best solution to decode html special character before
>   passing it to the data processing?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700326/decode-amp-back-to-in-javascript

Comment: @Candide its totally different problem.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. Obvioisly something is going utterly wrong.

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596859/post-table-data-to-action-which-is-dynamically-added-to-datatable)

Comment: @davidkonrad also check [this discussion](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1241/special-characters) on datatable forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Encode HTML entities:**

```
var valEncoded = $('<div>').text(val).html();
```

**Decode HTML entities:**

```
var valDecoded = $('<div>').html(val).text();
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/nyvsdk1g/) for code and demonstration.

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccmeuLzu/3/) for demonstration on how it could be used in your project.

Comment: mate I have updated the question with the fiddle, kindly see the fiddle.

Comment: mate, what is the difference between my answer and your answer? can you please elaborate in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript/4835406#4835406) of Stackoverflow, the solution for question is the function below to decode the html characters from a row of data.

```
function decodeHtml(str) {
    var map =
    {
        '&amp;': '&',
        '&lt;': '<',
        '&gt;': '>',
        '&quot;': '"',
        '&#039;': "'"
    };
    return str.replace(/&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|&quot;|&#039;/g, function (m) { return map[m]; 
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a kind of "hack", not a solid solution.

Comment: Yeah, but I am still looking for the best solution.