# Primefaces datatable displaying weird chars (ex: '<' is displayed as '&lt;')

Tags: primefaces

I have a primefaces datatable that displays some data (strings), and certain chars are being displayed by their character reference rather than the actual character I want. Some examples are '<','>','&' which are displayed as '&lt','>','&' respectively. These strings are displayed elsewhere on my app with no issue, however they are not in a datatable.

I tried using a converter which would return the following:

```java
return URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

however this just displayed the same thing

the short version of my primefaces code for my datatable is as follows:

```html
<p:dataTable var="exportDeclarationResult"
                    value="#{advancedSearchBean.result}"
                    lazy="true"
                    rows="25"
                    paginator="true"
                    paginatorPosition="bottom" 
                    paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
                    pageLinks="#{uiStandardBean.paginatorNumberOfPageLinks}"
                    paginatorTemplate="#{uiStandardBean.paginatorTemplate}"
                    currentPageReportTemplate="#{uiStandardBean.paginatorCurrentPageReportTemplate}"
                    emptyMessage="#{msg['15002']}">

                    <p:column  width="15%" headerText="#{msg['adSearch.exporter']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{exportDeclarationResult.exporterName}" converter="#{SpecialCharConverter}"/>
                    </p:column> 
                </p:dataTable>
```

My suspicion is that this has to do with the use of datatable, but I am not sure. If anyone has an idea on why this is happening, I would appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: If you suspect something, try without and see if it works then... And read about [mcve] please.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing issues with special characters that will need to be unescaped before they're printed. Be *very* careful with this if the data being unescaped is user input, as the characters can be interpreted by the browser as html or js rather than data.

[Datatable Jquery special character encoding and decoding to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605194/datatable-jquery-special-character-encoding-and-decoding-to-html) - this question is related and should have what you need in it

Comment: You are mixing things up (I suspect or OP is usimg misleading terminology) If you have '<' in string in a backing bean and display it via an `h:outputText` it **is** displayed as a `<` and only in the html source you see a `&lt;`, not on your screen. So if OP see's `&lt;` on the screen, something else is going on. If OP is seeing things wrong in the source, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662851/component-to-inject-and-interpret-string-with-html-code-into-jsf-page is the duplicate