# rows().every function not working in jquery binded datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Hi I am using jquery datatable in my MVC page so .In 1 page I have to send all the data from the datatable to the controller. So what I did is I made all the datas into 1 array and I passed it to the controller. using code

```
 var AllSelectedData = [];
var selected = [];
    table = $('#Distpopup').DataTable();
    table.rows().every(function () {
        var d = this.data();
        AllSelectedData.push(d);
    });
    $("#dtlist").val(AllSelectedData);
```

It is working fine for model binded datatable  but in 1 case I am having a datatable which is binded using ajax in that case it is not working.Any suggestions

Comment: is there any error message in console? and can you show full script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access all the rows of the table in model binding and also in Ajax.

e.g. this is your datatable initialization.

```
var table = $('#Distpopup').DataTable();
```

After adding data to the table you want to get this data in an array. If you want to send data to the controller use JSON.stringify() to stringfy your data and then send it to the controller and you can use it in model binding with a form field or also you can pass this stringfy data using Ajax request.

```
var AllSelectedData = [];
table.rows().every(function () {
     var d = this.data();
     AllSelectedData.push(d);
});

$("#dtlist").val(JSON.stringify(AllSelectedData));
```

I also face this issue see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42596859/7456905) that it still has no answer.

Comment: My Issue is that in case of jquery binded datatable . It is not even goin inside rows().every function . I am getting the AllSelectedData array as null

Comment: see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596859/post-table-data-to-action-which-is-dynamically-added-to-datatable) and follow the steps then post if you still have problem.

Comment: and please update your question that how you are initializing the table object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datatable callbacks, http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks

> One way to do it using initcomplete callback function which works when
>   the table has been initialised.

```
$('#Distpopup').DataTable({
          //Other settings
         "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
               console.log(json.data);
            },
});
```

> Another way using createdrow function which works every row created

```
var AllSelectedData = [];
    $('#Distpopup').DataTable({
              //Other settings
            "createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
                  AllSelectedData.push(data);
                },
    });
```